# How to unzip multiple gz files in python using multi threading?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, gzip

I have multiple gz files with a total size of around 120GB. I want to unzip(gzip) those files to the same directory and remove the existing gz file. Currently we are doing it manually and it is taking more time to unzip using `gzip -d <filename>`.
Is there a way I can unzip those files in parallel by creating a python script or any other technique. Currently these files are on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this very easily with [multiprocessing Pools](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

```
import gzip
import multiprocessing
import shutil

filenames = [
    'a.gz',
    'b.gz',
    'c.gz',
    ...
]

def uncompress(path):
    with gzip.open(path, 'rb') as src, open(path.rstrip('.gz'), 'wb') as dest:
        shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest)

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(uncompress, filenames, chunksize=1):
        pass
```

This code will spawn a few processes, and each process will extract one file at a time.

Here I've chosen `chunksize=1`, to avoid stalling processes if some files are bigger than average.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for your reply.So if i understand correctly.We are processing 4 files at a time right? if the one file is finished then it will pick the next file(5th file).Please confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, what if i dont want to hardcode the files instead passing the directory location so that it will pick up the files.Does pool.imap_unordered method accept the directory location as input for filenames?

Comment: @user3743797: well, you can do whatever you want. `filenames` here is hardcoded, but it can be the result of [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/glob.html#glob.glob). It's up to you.

Comment: I wouldn't pass the number of processes to the `Pool`. The optimal number depends on the number of cores and `Pool` by default uses the right number. Forcing 4 has only one "positive" effect that you know how many processes will be used (which may be useful in debugging) and a strong negative effect that on 4-core cpus it does the exact same thing as `Pool()` and on any other cpu will run slower.

Comment: @Bakuriu: right. It was nice to have a number for easier analyzability, but I agree that it's better to avoid that

Answer (score 2):

A large segment of of the wall clock time spent decompressing a file with `gunzip` or `gzip -d` will be from the I/O operations (reading and writing to disk). It might even be more than the time spent actually decompressing data. You can take advantage of this by having multiple gzip jobs going in the background. As some jobs are blocked on I/O, another job can actually run without having to wait in a queue.

You can speed up the decompressing of the entire file set by having multiple `gunzip` processes running in the background. Each serving a specific set of files.

You can whip up something easy in BASH.  Split the file list into separate commands and use the `&` to start it as a background job. Then `wait` for each each job to finish.

I would recommend that you have between 2 to 2*N jobs going at once.  Where N is the number of cores or logical processors on your computer. Experiment as appropriate to get the right number.

You can whip something up easy in BASH.

```
#!/bin/bash

argarray=( "$@" )
len=${#argarray[@]}

#declare 4 empty array sets
set1=()
set2=()
set3=()
set4=()

# enumerate over each argument passed to the script
# and round robin add it to one of the above arrays

i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]
do

    if [ $i -lt $len ]; then
        set1+=( "${argarray[$i]}" )
        ((i++))
    fi

    if [ $i -lt $len ]; then
        set2+=( "${argarray[$i]}" )
        ((i++))
    fi

    if [ $i -lt $len ]; then
        set3+=( "${argarray[$i]}" )
        ((i++))
    fi

    if [ $i -lt $len ]; then
        set4+=( "${argarray[$i]}" )
        ((i++))
    fi
done

# for each array, start a background job
gzip -d ${set1[@]} &
gzip -d ${set2[@]} &
gzip -d ${set3[@]} &
gzip -d ${set4[@]} &

# wait for all jobs to finish    
wait
```

In the above example, I picked 4 files per job and started two separate jobs.  You can easily extend the script to have more jobs, more files per process, and to take the file names as command line parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want to automate this process.Suppose i have 50 files in my directory then i want these to be unzipped parallel so that i can reduce the time.Currently i have file names with standard sequence numbers from 01 to 50 so i am passing first 10 files in one gzip command like wise i have 5 processes.So i want to create a thread for first 5 jobs like wise i can start 10 threads.My question is is it possible in python?

Comment: With a little bit of bash scripting, you can get this.  Convert the command line parameters of your bash script into an array. Then split into 4 separate arrays.   Each array becomes a separate `gzip -d` call.  I'll see if I can work something up later...

Comment: @user3743797 - now it works.  You can invoke `script.sh *.gz` or  and it will do exactly what you want. I would suggest having the script in a separate directory from the set of files you want to operate on.